# Exception thrown, catch part ignored

Tags: android, exception, nfc

I am facing `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.nfc.NdefRecord.createUri` exception from this piece of code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
   mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
   try {
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
        } else {
            NdefRecord uriRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(someUri);
            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {uriRecord});
            mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(msg, this);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "initNfcNdefMessage()", e);
    }
}
```

but, `initNfcNdefMessage` **is not printed** in stack trace. How is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is not derived from the Exception class.

You are trying to catch it by Exception object but it is originally of throwable

check this

```
java.lang.Object
  extended byjava.lang.Throwable
      extended byjava.lang.Error
          extended byjava.lang.LinkageError
              extended byjava.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
                  extended byjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

[Refer here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)

Answer (score 5):

Java has multiple exception hierarchies.

Your problem is that [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) is not derived from [java.lang.Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) so you cannot catch NoSuchMethodError by catching Exception.  You would need to catch NoSuchMethodError explicitly or you could catch Throwable instead.

See the article on [Effective Java Exceptions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html) to understand more about checked exceptions.